How can I non-destructively blind/cover one drosophila eye for behavioural assays?
I am looking for a protocol for non-destructively covering one eye of Drosophila for a behavioural and subsequent imaging experiment I am planning. I am aware of using wax to paint over the entire eye based on conversations with my PI, but cannot find any papers that use this technique. Any searches along the lines of "drosophila monocular eye covering/blinding/etc" have turned up fruitless (drosophila pun intended). If you know of any papers that use this technique or similar, I would appreciate your help.

Our lab hasn't published anything using this method, but in some preliminary experiments we used a soft pencil eyeliner to draw over the Drosophila eye. It worked pretty well, except with enough time the flies can clean/rub it off with their legs. We also tried black nailpolish, but it dried as a scary spike on the eye so I don't recommend that.

Coooooooooooool
